# Reading GPIO internal registers using sysfs

Tags: embedded-linux, gpio, i2c

I am using a PCA9544 GPIO expander in embedded Linux.  The driver is installed and controlling GPIO as expected.  However, I would like to read the values of the INTn lines through the control register using sysfs.  Is there a file associated with the control register?

Comment: Highly unlikely.  The abstractions presented by **sysfs** are intended to hide HW details such as device registers.

Comment: @sawdust: That's too bad because the only way to find out which of its MUXed interrupt input channels interrupted is to read the control register.  Seems like any useful driver would have that functionality available.

Comment: A device driver (which is part of the kernel) would not be using **sysfs** (which is for userspace).  There is a kernel interface for drivers to acquire a GPIO and use it as an interrupt source.

Comment: @sawdust: The chip multiplexes the interrupts to produce one interrupt to the processor.  In order to know which line interrupted, one must read an internal register.

Answer (score 1):

If you export single GPIOs, you can wait for its interrupt on per GPIO basis. Take a look at [libsoc](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc) project. It handles sysfs calls for you. Look at [libsoc_gpio_wait_interrupt](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc/blob/master/lib/include/libsoc_gpio.h#L198) and [libsoc_gpio_callback_interrupt](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc/blob/master/lib/include/libsoc_gpio.h#L212) routines. All you have to do it to activate required GPIOs, configure them as input and specify trigger edge (see options below), after this you can use interrupt routines. I've also an i2c based GPIO expander and it works.

```
typedef enum {
    EDGE_ERROR = -1,
    RISING = 0,
    FALLING = 1,
    NONE = 2,
    BOTH = 3,
} gpio_edge;
```